# Unreliable HDMI from Gateway Laptop to Pioneer HD TV

Tags: laptop, video, hdmi, tv

How to improve reliability when connecting Gateway M-1618 laptop with a Pioneer KRP-500M TV using HDMI?

Problem is that HDMI connection dissappears every minute or so for about 1-2 seconds. That is TV goes blank. This happens when using resolution native to laptop 1280x800.

What I have tried:

- switched HDMI cable (no improvement)
- tried both HDMI connections on TV (no improvement)
- switched display mode to HDMI out only (blank laptop screen) unsure if this helped
- changed display resolution to 800x600 (this seems to help, but is not optimal!)

Specs:
Laptop Gateway M1618:

- graphics ATI Radeon X1270 256MB hypermemory
- native resolution 1280x800 (WXGA)
- HDMI 1.2

TV

- Technology   TFT active matrix
- Resolution   1920 x 1080
- Display Format   1080p (FullHD)
- 2 HDMI connections (19 pin Type A) unsure what standard it supports

My theory is that something can't handle larger data streams that 1280x800 provide (as opposed to 800x600), or there is some sync problem.
TV plays Blue Ray fine, so the problem more likely is with laptop.

Hoping someone more experienced with HDMI can provide some ideas to try.

Comment: It could be that your TV can't support 1280X800 try 1280X720 and see if it continues this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in the specs for the TV it will handle 1080p which is 1920*1080 progressive; your notebook video card should support this output with it's drivers especially if you are using an HDMI cable; I would force this display setting and check it out.

Also do you have actual HDMI output from your card or are you using DVI-I as most cards have not not the DVI-D (which is true HD ie HDMI=DVI-D)

If you have a DVI-I and using an adapter to HDMI then you loose quality but you can use an adapter from DVI-D (dual link) to HDMI with same-same compatibility

If you are using HDMI output dirrectly than there is no worry; just check the above.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your video driver on the laptop?

http://support.gateway.com/product/default.aspx?partNumber=1014906R

.

"Hypermemory" is shared main memory, be sure it is set to use all 256mb of shared memory.

Some systems you can change this shared setting some you cannot, check the bios and video properties.

You may have to change the hertz setting (refresh rate) in video properties when connected to the TV.

.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this post and previously give some hints in a similar situation that might help.

*Below some hints/suggestions in how to tackle this. Before you proceed a full backup is also advised.*

For the Power settings For Windows 10:
Click the Windows Start menu and start typing Control Panel.
Open the Control Panel and Type Power in the Search Box.
Click in Edit power plan(window will open).
Click in Change advanced power settings(new window will open).
For troubleshooting purposes: 
In that window, set all the Power Battery settings as Plugged in.
If the issue is fixed, later attempt the changes 1 by 1 until you figure which is the one affecting your computer.

This could still be a driver issue, try also Older drivers.
I had an old laptop that only a far older driver was giving  less issues going to stand by that the updated ones. 
If you already attempted all the know drivers, skip to the last suggestion.

If the issue is the video card, try ruling out the Operating System(Windows 10 here for what I read) by loading other system like Linux in a flash drive or something.

I hope this helps,
Ramon